# biblatex: Enhancing \autocite in case of would-be nested footnotes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, nesting

> **This question led to a new feature in a package:**
>   [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)

`biblatex` provides high-level citation commands like `\autocite` that allow "global switching from inline citations to citations given in footnotes (or as superscripts)" (manual, p. 81). `\autocite` and `\textcite` (the command for use in the flow of text) form the two "standard" citation commands.

So what if I use `\footnote` to write an explanatory note and need to cite a source? With author-year styles, `\autocite` will be mapped to `\parencite` which (naturally) also works in footnotes. On the other hand, with author-title styles (or if I explicitly declared `[autocite=footnote]` in the preamble), mapping to `\footcite` would produce nested footnotes, and these are not possible with standard LaTeX. In this case, the "sensible thing" would be to map `\autocite` to an alternative citation command admissible in footnotes (e.g. `\parencite`). Unfortunately, `biblatex` simply gobbles the out-of-place citation (and typesets spurious braces).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear,%
  autocite=footnote,% Without this option, \autocite works in footnotes
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text.\footnote{A footnote \autocite{A01}.}

Some text.\footnote{A footnote \parencite{A01}.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The obvious workaround is to use `\parencite` (or whatever low-level citation command is appropriate for the style) in footnotes. But this goes against the idea of high-level citation markup.

Is it possible to enhance `\autocite` so that it will automatically switch to an alternative low-level citation command in case of would-be nested footnotes?

UPDATE: I have submitted a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3201298&group_id=244752&atid=1126006) at SourceForge.net: biblatex.

Comment: probably one for c.t.t, as Philipp does not read this site, and I suspect this is really a feature request for `biblatex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature has been implemented in `biblatex` v1.3 (released March 14th, 2011). See also the new `\smartcite` command (manual, section 3.7.2).