# Biblatex \autocite in case of would-be nested footnotes

Tags: biblatex, formatting, footnotes, citing

I have the same situation as the following user:
[biblatex: Enhancing \autocite in case of would-be nested footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11151/biblatex-enhancing-autocite-in-case-of-would-be-nested-footnotes)

I want to use `\autocite` within a `\footnote`.  This results in the citation being wrapped in parenthesis.  I want to change the behavior of `\autocite` used within `\footnote` to print the citation without the parenthesis like a simple call of `\cite` would do.

How can I change the behavior of `\autocite` within the `\footnote`?

Comment: Which citation style (`authoryear`, `authortitle`, ...) do you use?

Comment: I use biblatex-juradiss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution depends on the citation style. For styles like `authortitle`, `verbose` and their respective variants (and also for `biblatex-juradiss`) that execute `autocite=footnote`, we only need to redefine the underlying `\smartcite` macro so that it does not add parentheses in footnotes (by replacing `\mkbibparens` with `\textnormal`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\smartcites}
    [\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]{\smartcite}{\multicitedelim}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text.\footnote{A footnote \autocite{A01}.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

For styles like `authoryear` that by default execute `autocite=inline` (which uses `\parencite`), we need to declare a new `autocite` option value (say, `inlineplainfootnote`) that points to a new underlying macro (say, `\mysmartcite`) that does what you want (add parentheses in normal text, don't add them in footnotes).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inlineplainfootnote}{\mysmartcite}{\mysmartcites}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\mysmartcite}[\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\mysmartcites}
    [\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibparens]{\mysmartcite}{\multicitedelim}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=inlineplainfootnote}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text.\footnote{A footnote \autocite{A01}.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]