# Restrict Idem tracker to the same footnote

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

I want to change the behavior of the biblatex-option `idemtracker=constrict`.  In the documentation it is described as follows:

> This mode is similar to context with one additional condition: a
>   reference in a footnote will only be considered as unambiguous if the
>   current citation and the previous citation are given **in the same
>   footnote or in immediately consecutive footnotes**.

Instread of the "same footnote or immediately consecutive footnotes", the idemtracker should only use idem if the citation is within the same footnote.

If the citation comes in the immediately consecutive footnote, the name of the author should be printed.  How can I change this behavior?

I am using `biblatex-juradiss`, which is based on `authortitle-dw`.  I have the `autocite=footnote` and the `\cite` command I am using creates either footnotes or within a footnote plain quotes (see [Biblatex \autocite in case of would-be nested footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/biblatex-autocite-in-case-of-would-be-nested-footnotes)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is probably best solved by patching the internal footnote test used for the `constrict` tracking mode. To change `constrict` mode for all trackers you can add the following to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@ifmpfncheck}{\tw@}{\@ne}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This example alters `constrict` mode only for the `idem` tracker.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=biblatex-juradiss]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\let\cbx@ifmpfncheck\blx@ifmpfncheck
\patchcmd{\cbx@ifmpfncheck}{\tw@}{\@ne}{}{}
\let\cbx@ifciteidem@constrict\blx@ifciteidem@constrict
\patchcmd{\cbx@ifciteidem@constrict}{\blx@ifmpfncheck}{\cbx@ifmpfncheck}{}{}
\let\blx@imc@ifciteidem\cbx@ifciteidem@constrict
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler.\footnote{Filler \cite{knuth:ct:a}. Filler \cite{knuth:ct:b}.}
Filler \autocite{knuth:ct:a}.
Filler \autocite{knuth:ct:a}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the style here uses the option settings

```
autocite=footnote,ibidtracker=constrict,idemtracker=constrict
```