# Bibliography string 'letterto' undefined

Tags: biblatex, letters

I'm using biblatex with the historian style, and everything's been working smoothly until I tried the `@letter` entry type. I'm also redefining the `\smartcite` macro to get the footnotes to look more like I prefer.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=historian,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@letter{saganA,
    author = {Sagan, Naomi},
    namec = {Greenpeace},
    Year = {24 February, 1990},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{literature.bib}

%% redefine the \smartcite macro so that it does not add parentheses in footnotes
%% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/biblatex-autocite-in-case-of-would-be-nested-footnotes
\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\smartcites}
    [\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]{\smartcite}{\multicitedelim}

\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearlist{address}
  \clearlist{location}
}

\begin{document}  
This is a test.\autocites{saganA}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting a warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Bibliography string 'letterto' undefined
(biblatex)                at entry 'saganA' on input line 35.
```

(where 35 is the last line "\end{document\")

And the output looks like this:

[image]

How can I replace "**letterto**" with "letter to" (not bold, with blank space) or get rid of it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Cheers! i will remember that for the next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  letterto = {letter to}
}
```

to provide the substitution of the `letterto`  biblatex string.

Comment: Oooh! that was a quick and handy solution. I'm a bit embarassed I didn't figure this out. Thanks!