# Bibliography string 'by' undefined in Canadian

Tags: biblatex, babel, languages, strings

I use `babel` with the `canadian` language, and `biblatex-chicago`. If I use a `@inbook` reference with a `bookauthor` field, I get the following error:

```
Bibliography string 'by' undefined at entry 'smith' on input line 104.
```

And `by` is shown in bold case as in [this other thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145592/bibliography-string-letterto-undefined).

I have tried using

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{canadian}{
  by = {by}
}
```

as suggested but it returns the following error:

```
Package keyval Error: by undefined.
```

If I simply switch to `english` in `babel`, the problem does not occur.

Comment: Is Canadian a valid option in babel?

Comment: @Aradnix Yes, it is.

Comment: Does `\NewBibliographyString{price}` make the error go away? The problem is that `biblatex-chicago` does not come with a `cms-canadian.lbx`, so a lot of strings might be missing, you could create your own `cms-canadian.lbx` from `cms-british.lbx`/`cms-american.lbx`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you make a more complete example?

Comment: @moewe I tried adding `\NewBibliographyString{by}` just before `\DefineBibliographyStrings` and yes it works, thank you very much :)
I think I would need to create a specific `cms-canadian.lbx` as you suggested; I will look into how I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the differences for canadian and british are small to non-existent. You could create an `lbx` file that inherits british and makes needed changes, or just map the canadian language to use the british biblatex-chicago localization file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[canadian]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{canadian}{cms-british}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{westfahl:space}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe the main difference between Canadian English and British English is the use of the American '-ize' suffix instead of the British '-ise' (organise, realise, etc.).