# biblatex \autocite in nested footnote confuses footnote numbering and test is lost for tufte-book

Tags: tufte, tufte-book

I use tufte-book and had a problem with nested footnotes. The solution shown  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/biblatex-autocite-in-case-of-would-be-nested-footnotes) works for me with document class `article` but not with `tufte-book`:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}  
% \documentclass  {article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\smartcites}
    [\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibfootnote]{\smartcite}{\multicitedelim}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text.\footnote{A footnote \autocite{A01}.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It does not include the text `A footnote` and confuses the numbering of the footnotes - note footnote 2 is referenced as 3!
[image: the pdf for tufte-book]
[image: the pdf for article note the index 2 resp. 3]