# Biblatex \autocite need adaption for nested footnotes for year-author in b=tufte-book

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

I need in a `tufte-book` citations with `author-year` and used the [recommendations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/biblatex-autocite-in-case-of-would-be-nested-footnotes) for the `author-year` style. Unlike the case there, I want

- the simple citation in regular text as sidenote (as is automatically produced with `autocite=footnote` and the tufte style) and
- a plain citation in footnotes.

I have tried to change the code given there to have autocite a footnote in regular text and a plain citation in a footnote, but have not succeeded.

What must be changed?

```
% \documentclass[a4paper,openany,nobib]{tufte-book}  
\documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage[style=authoryear,
                autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
    
    \DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inlineplainfootnote}{\mysmartcite}{\mysmartcites}
    
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\mysmartcite}[\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibparens]
      {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
      {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
       \usebibmacro{cite}}
      {\multicitedelim}
      {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
    
    \DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\mysmartcites}
        [\iffootnote\textnormal\mkbibparens]{\mysmartcite}{\multicitedelim}
    
    \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=inlineplainfootnote}
    
    % \usepackage{filecontents}
    
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{A01,
      author = {Author, A.},
      year = {2001},
      title = {Alpha},
    }
    @misc{B02,
      author = {Poet, B.},
      year = {2002},
      title = {Beta},
    }
    \end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text with a reference \autocite{A01} which should become a sidenote i.e. 1 and the sidenote should say: (Author 2001) .

Some more text with a citation which should become a footnote or sidenote saying: Author 2001, Poet 2002 \autocite{A01, B02}.

Some text with a footnote \footnote{A footnote with \autocite{B02}.} which should say: 1 A footnote with (Poet 2002).

And some text with a footnote with two citations \footnote{Two citations\autocite{B02, A01}} which should say: 2 Two citations(Poet 2002; Author 2001).


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Aside: I have added a second bib entry, but it cannot be found. what is wrong there?

Comment: What do you mean by "plain citation"? Can you show us what the output should look like in the example?

Comment: As to your aside: `filecontents` does not overwrite an existing file. So if you started out with a `.bib` file of the same basename as your `.tex` file or edited the `filecontents` later to include the second reference, the old file with the old contents will stick around. I get two working citations in your example. Delete the test `.bib` file (and the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf`) and try again.

Comment: @moewe - I have put the expected output in the example file. thank you for asking! - I recently switched to vscode with latex-workshop and did not see that `clean up` did not delete the .bib file - I expected the error in missing `,` or similar.

Comment: @user855443 Note you should be **very** glad VSC doesn't delete your bibliography database!

Comment: @cfr - I have my true bib files stored somewhere else, but I can see your point.  It is just another piece of information somebody not using latex every day may not have present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to define any new citation commands: You could be pretty happy with the standard `\smartcite` approach were it not for the fact that `biblatex` can't detect footnotes in `tufte-book`. So all we need to do is make it detect footnotes. This is done by inserting `\toggletrue{blx@footnote}` in the right place in the footnote implementation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,nobib]{tufte-book}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@footnotetext[2][0pt]{%
  \marginpar{%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \def\baselinestretch {\setspace@singlespace}%
    \reset@font\footnotesize%
    \@tufte@margin@par% use parindent and parskip settings for marginal text
    \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}\noindent%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark%
    }%
    \color@begingroup%
       \@makefntext{%
         \toggletrue{blx@footnote}%
         \ignorespaces #2%
       }%
    \color@endgroup%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Some text with a reference \autocite{sigfridsson}

Some more text with a citation\autocite{sigfridsson, nussbaum}.

Some text with a footnote \footnote{A footnote with \autocite{nussbaum}.}

And some text with a footnote with two citations \footnote{Two citations\autocite{nussbaum, sigfridsson}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998. 2 Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Nussbaum 1978. 3 A footnote with (Nussbaum 1978). 4 Two citations(Nussbaum 1978; Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998)]

Note that this does not include parentheses in footnotes that contain only citations.

Comment: Excellent - worked immediately and solved a vexing problem with footnotes in footnotes for the tufte style (the mechanism should probably be incorporated somewhere in the style?). I am impressed with the simplicity of the solution! Thanks a lot!